# Restriction of a self adjoint operator to a closed subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

Let A be a self adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$ (possibly unbounded, densely defined with domain $D(A)$
) and let $F$ be a closed subspace of $H$.
My question is: If $D(A)\cap F$ is a dense subspace of $F$ and $A(D(A)\cap F) \subset F$ , the restriction of $A$ to $F$ becomes self adjoint ?

If this statement is true, we can find some eigenvalues embedded in continuous spectrum of $A$ easily, by checking out the descrete spectrums of $A|_F$.
So I'm interested in wether this statement is true or not.

Comment: $A\rvert_F = (A^\dagger)\rvert_F\subseteq (A\rvert_F)^\dagger$, but it's not enough.  You need to assume $D(A) = (D(A)\cap F)\oplus(D(A)\cap F^\perp)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Certainly , the contition you exibited seems to be essential  to show $A|_F\supset (A|_F)'$ .